# How to create a special graph?

Tags: graph, unique, lattice, subgraph

I wish to generate an undirected lattice graph *G* with following features:

1. It has *m*x*n* vertexes;
2. Each vertex has only two kinds of labels (0 or 1);
3. Every *t*x*t* subgraph is unique.

For example, if the array of the vertex label of lattice graph *G* is

```
1 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1
```

then any 3x3 subgraph of *G* is unique (only one isomorphism can be found).
For example, subgraph

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

can only be the top-left block of *G*, 90 degree rotated.

---

Actually, I can generate such graphs by wave function collapsing.
The example above is generated in this way.

However, I want to go further.
Here are the true questions:

1. If the subgraph can be any shape (with at least *t* vertex), how to generate the graph *G*?
2. If graph *G* is not limited in lattice shape, what will happen?
3. What are the relationships between the shapes of subgraph, and the minimum vertex number *t* to make them unique?

Any idea or keyword?

Comment: you should ask this on the math stackexchange. you should also clarify/explain more thoroughly. best to lead with examples.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your suggestion. I have rewritten the question.